# drupal 7 use colorbox in views field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, colorbox, drupal-views

For a website I'm building I'm trying to have some image fields (which are in a view) use colorbox. I've tried this tutorial: http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/colorbox-drupal/ however to no avail. This is the page I'm trying to get it working on: http://woningidee.nl/project/10

I have installed the modules and uploaded the library. I've changed the display of the image in the content type to use colorbox but it all doesn't work..

Anybody an idea where things go wrong?

Comment: What doesn't work on your page? I can see popups integrated with the views module ...

Comment: Perfect, it somehow now works..